# Tell nagios not to warn about non-critical updates

Tags: apt, monitoring, nagios, icinga2

I use nagios to warn if there are apt updates available on my Debian buster server, but I want to use this option:

```
-o, --only-critical
  Only warn about upgrades matching the critical list.  The total number
  of upgrades will be printed, but any non-critical upgrades will not cause
  the plugin to return WARNING status.
```

so I edited `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/apt.cfg`:

```
# 'check_apt' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_apt
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt --only-critical
}

# 'check_apt_distupgrade' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_apt_distupgrade
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt --only-critical -d
}
```

But still I get emails containing something like:

```
***** Service Monitoring on freifunk *****

apt on vm02.freifunk is WARNING!

Info:    APT WARNING: 2 packages available for upgrade (0 critical updates).
```

Although I have installed `monitoring-plugins-basic` 2.2-6 and
the `--only-critical` option was added in `release-2.3.3` it is working already:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt
APT WARNING: 2 packages available for upgrade (0 critical updates). |available_upgrades=2;;;0 critical_updates=0;;;0
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt --only-critical
APT OK: 2 packages available for upgrade (0 critical updates). |available_upgrades=2;;;0 critical_updates=0;;;0
```

But the command option I set in the nagios config seems to be ignored.

I also tried the latest version manually installed from [this source](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-plugins-installing-nagios-plugins-from-source-569.html#Debian), but it didn't change the outcome. Maybe is there another way to achieve this? maybe just change the line in command_line to something, that greps the result somehow?

it seems like the nagios plugins are used by `icinga2`. This is a part of `/etc/icinga2/constants.conf`:

```
/* The directory which contains the plugins from the Monitoring Plugins project. */
const PluginDir = "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins"
```

How do I properly tell nagios not to warn about non-critical updates?

Comment: Can you please verify the config path? You talk about `/etc/nagios/config` and `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/`. Is the correct config used?

Comment: @BekoPharm, yes, I added my answer

Comment: If the plugin works correctly from CLI (which it seems to do), you can at least be sure that it's a configuration issue. You might want to investigate where you're seeing the problem (what host/service), what command that check is using and go from there. Note that if this is a remote check (NRPE for example) the used plugin is on the receiving node, not the node running Nagios.